# circular import issue only occurs from console but works fine when running as main

Tags: python-3.x, circular-dependency

i have a simple python file, named filename.py.

```
from x import y

if __name__ == '__main__':
    y.callable()
```

if i open the python console in pycharm, and simply call `from x import y` i get an error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name ... from partially initialized module  (most likely due to a circular import)
```

While if i simply run the file (`python -m filename.py`) everything works fine, and i dont get any import error.

what is the reason for such difference?